# Grails 2.4 throws EHCache class not found error

Tags: grails, ehcache

I created a fresh Grails 2.4 project, removed hibernate and database migration plugin added latest spring security and mongo db plugin and when I ran `grails compile` I got following error

`| Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

If I remove spring security plugin it compiles and if I remove mongoDB plugin and use spring-security with hibernate it still works only the combination of spring security with solo mongoDB plugin is giving above error.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like spring-security depends on ehcache, but doesn't declare as such. We had a similar problem with the `cache` plugin depending on ehcache. Add this to the `dependencies` section of your BuildConfig:

```
compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8"
```

Comment: This fixes the issue but I have tried similar combination with grails 2.3.8 i.e. just spring-security and mongoDB and it used to work. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Probably because ehcache used to be a core dependency of the framework, but no longer is